# How many ways to take presents to school

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently trying to figure out a question dealing with counting. I believe I have an answer (Or at least a way to do it) and was wondering if you could confirm/deny my suspicions, and possibly give a new idea if I'm going at this the wrong way.

"Billy got twelve different Christmas presents this year. He asks his mother if he can take them to school on the first day after break. His mother says he can take some, but not all of the presents. How many choices does Billy have, assuming he is going to take at least one present?"

**My attempt**: Seeing as how it is at least one present, and not more than 11 (cause he can't take all), I assumed the complement rule would be useful here. The total possibilities to take all presents is $12!$, and then there is one case in that where he takes all 12 presents. So the total number of possibilities would be $12! - 1$?

If that is not correct, the only other method I can come up with is if we added up $P(12,1) + P(12,2) + ... + P(12,11)$, but this seems rather tedious so I figured there must be an easier way.

Any confirmation/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $12!$ is the number of ways to _order_ the presents, but we aren't doing that. The number of subsets of $n$-element set is $2^n$. Also, you have to exclude two possibilities: he won't take all and he won't take none.

Comment: So the answer would be 2^n -2?

Comment: Yes, of course with $n=12$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think to use sets/subsets as a counting method. Haven't used that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $$\sum_{i=1}^{12} {12 \choose i}$$  From the above expression, we can get ${n\choose 0} + \dots + {n\choose n}=2^n$. Here, at least one is the condition, so the total amount of ways are $2^{12}-2=4094$.

Comment: To type $$\sum_{i = 1}^{12} \binom{12}{i}$$ type \sum_{i = 1}^{12} \binom{12}{i} when you are in display math mode.  Also, note that he can not take all of the presents.  How does that affect the indices in your summation?